# Rows added but data not displayed on datagridview in vs2010

Tags: c#-3.0

Here is my code; loaddata method extracts data from student table and it returns datatable named "tbl_std". from button click I want to load data into datagridview and code is below. It only displays number of blank rows that are in the database table but not data. Help me as soon as possible......

private DataTable loaddata()

{

```
        sqlcon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from student",sqlcon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlcon.Close();
        sda.Fill(ds, "tbl_std");
        return ds.Tables["tbl_std"];
```

}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = loaddata();

    }
```

Comment: Is `AutoGenerateColumns` enabled? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.100).ASPX (you might want to define the columns yourself - but this should work with the flag being set) ... and pls think a bit about your naming styles - this will get unreadable/unmaintainable soon if you don't even set a name

Comment: Hi Carsten Konig, No it's not AutogenerateColumns enabled. I have form having text boxes to take inputs like name, address,contact,gender and button to save into database and in onClick event of that button I have written insert sql query to table student and that worked. In same envent of same button there is also above code dataGridView1.DataSource = loaddata();
This didn't work so I put next button i.e. button4 and code is above mentioned. It only adds rows but not displayed data in rows when i click on button4 every time after inserting data.

Comment: Hey CarstenKönig, I ignored that problem and left it as it is. But today I saw this post again and I myself saw my mistake too. That is I have to bind data in gridview like: DataGridView1.DataBind(); It is because I do same data binding after datasource setting in ASP.NET.